# the probability for a file to be completed under random distribution

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

Suppose there are $n$ files, for ease lets assume all are of the same size $S$.
Further suppose that each second, you obtain some fraction of size $k<<S$ (packet size) that is a part of one of the $n$ files, 
A file is completed after $t$ seconds if all of its $S/k$ packets were obtained.
How do I calculate the probability that for one specific file (say file $i$) is completed after $T$ seconds.
By one specific file I meant some file to clarify,
The settings is similar to how torrent p2p network works.

Comment: Can you get the same part multiple times?  Or just a random part you have not seen before of some file?

Comment: two differentcases obviously, lets assume not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved using dynamic programming. I've taken liberty to redefine terminology a little. Suppose we have $n$ files, each of size $k$ [information units]. I assume that we source only absent pieces, so each second we receive a random new $1$ information unit on one of files, all pieces are equiprobable.

Since you're interested in one specific file, we can treat it as having file $1$ of size $k$ and file $2$ of size $(n-1)k$. Denote current state at time $t$ as $\{X_1, X_2\}$, where $X_1$ is size of file $1$ and $X_2$ is size of file $2$.

Then, at time $t + 1$ your state becomes $\{X_1 + 1, X_2\}$ with probability $$\frac{k - X_1}{nk-(X_1 + X_2)},$$

or $\{X_1, X_2 + 1\}$ with probability $$\frac{(n - 1)k - X_2}{nk - (x_1 + X_2)}.$$

You start at $\{0, 0\}$, and have to find $\mathrm{P}_{\{k - 1, T - k\}}\cdot\mathrm{P}_{\{k - 1, T - k\}\rightarrow\{k, T - k\}}$.

**ADDITION:** Turns out a closed form might be obtained. Probability of finishing file $1$ exactly at time $T$ is

$$
\binom{T - 1}{T - k}\Biggr/\binom{nk}{k}
$$

**ADDITION:** If you're interested in time $T$ when any file completes (I assume you want the time of first occurence only) - this is more complex, as we can't simplify it to 2-files case.

The dynamic programming approach still works, though the calculations become much heavier. In any case, at discrete time moment $t$ you have state $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}, \sum_i x_i = t$, where $x_i$ - size of file $i$ at time $t$. In general, for each $x_i < k$ you can make transition

$$
\{x_1, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_n\} \rightarrow \{x_1, \ldots, x_i + 1, \ldots, x_n\} \qquad \mathrm{with}\:\mathrm{probability} \qquad \frac{k - x_i}{nk - t}.
$$

At step $T - 1$, if you have states $S$ from the set $\mathbb{S}_{T - 1}$ of all possible states with at least one $x_i = k - 1$ - you can complete a file on the next step. Specifically, probability of completing file at step $T$ would be

$$
\sum_{S \in \mathbb{S}_{t - 1}: N(S) >= 1}\mathrm{Pr}(S)\cdot\frac{N(S)}{nk - (T - 1)},
$$

where $N(S)$ is how many files of size $k - 1$ is in state $S$.

This approach would demand reasonable time and memory space for small $n$ and $k$. On my potato computer it takes $2.7$ seconds to process case of $5$ files of $10$ pieces each, and $93$ seconds to process $5$ files of $20$ pieces each.

Now, there might be a chance to solve it analytically, but I haven't reached  a closed form yet. Probability of being in a state $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$ at time $t$ might be calculated as

$$
\frac{\biggl(k\cdot(k - 1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(k - x_1 + 1)\biggr)\cdot\ldots\cdot\biggl(k\cdot(k - 1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(k - x_n + 1)\biggr)}{\biggl((nk)\cdot(nk - 1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(nk - t + 1)\biggr)}\cdot\frac{t!}{x_1!\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n!} = \ \ldots = \frac{\displaystyle{\frac{k!}{(k - x_1)!}}\cdot\displaystyle{\frac{k!}{(k - x_2)!}}\cdot\ldots\cdot\displaystyle{\frac{k!}{(k - x_n)!}}}{\displaystyle{\frac{(nk)!}{(nk - t)!}}}\cdot\frac{t!}{x_1!\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n!}
$$

Next, probably, a sum of all possible combinations of $\mathrm{Pr}(S) \in \mathbb{S}_{t - 1}$ where there is $1, 2, \ldots$ states with $x_i = k - 1$ simplifies to a closed form, but I didn't reach it. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the math articulation, can you elaborate on why the probability is defined as you wrote?

Comment: If at the time $t$ you have $X_1$ pieces in file $1$ and $X_2$ in file $2$ - that means that your next choice is from $k - X_1$ remaining pieces of file $1$ and $(n - 1)k - X_2$ pieces of file $2$. Hence, probability to get new piece of file $1$ is $\frac{k - X_1}{k - X_1 + (n - 1)k - X_2} = \frac{k - X_1}{nk - t}$ (because at all times you have $X_1 + X_2 = t$).

Comment: Since you need the probability of file $1$ being completed exactly on time $T$, you want to have $k - 1$ pieces on time $T - 1$ and receive final piece on time $T$, which is $\mathrm{P}_{\{k - 1, T - k\}}\cdot\frac{1}{nk - T + 1}$.

Comment: thanks for the extra details. I'm not sure I understand this line: "Since you're interested in one specific file, we can treat it as having file 1 of size k and file 2 of size (n−1)k", I'm guess I meant to ask what is the probability to get at least one completed file after T seconds in my notation. I may be wrong but I think its very different probabilities, the  translation to 2 files does not hold  I think (consider getting the first k parts of one of the files that is in one of the "2" it will complete but we miss it.

Comment: _"How do I calculate the probability that for one specific file (say file $i$) is completed after $T$ seconds"_ implies that you're interested in one exact file and don't care what happens to the other files. In this case, without any loss of generality you can enumerate the one file you're interested in as $1$, and treat all the rest as huge bulk file $2$ of size $(n-1)k$. You'll miss when one of the files that got absorbed in $2$ completes, even if before file $1$, but that's fine, since you're interested in specific file $1$.

Comment: Now, if you're interested in probability of finishing any file at time $T$ (I assume that you want only the first occasion) - that's trickier. I'll add my thoughts to the reply.

Comment: thanks  the clarification and addition of the case I was interested in, I'm reading through and try to actually get some sort of "feeling" on how this  probability behaves (I was actually interested in the opposite (the case where no single file was completed) and understand if its a rare occasion and from which T it becomes 0. I'll try work it out from your addition.

Comment: Well, if you reach the answer you're satisfied with - please post it here. You probably noticed that $\mathrm{Pr}(x_1, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_j, \ldots, x_n) = \mathrm{Pr}(x_1, \ldots, x_j, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_n)$. In other words, state probability doesn't depend on files enumeration, which simplifies summation.